# Are half-elves of Birthright immortal?

Tags: adnd-2e, aging, half-elf, birthright

In Birthright, elves are immortal, like stated in Rulebook, page 7:

> Cerilian elves are creatures of faerie dust and starlight, gifted with
>   immortality and powers of mind and body beyond those of humanity.

They are only mortal in the Shadow World, as stated in Bloodspawn, page 27:

> Unless slain, seelie faeries are immortal in the Shadow World but
>   mortal in Cerilia. Conversely, elves are immortal in Cerilia but
>   mortal in the Shadow World.

But nothing is said about half-elves in Rulebook beyond their resistance of 30% against aging attacks (elves have total immunity) and the elves treating them as Sidhelien (cerilian name of the race) and welcoming them fully in elven society.

However, in High Mage Aelies (a blooded half-elf mage npc) description in The Book of Magecraft, page 33, is said:

> Aelies is rumored to be ancient - hundreds upon hundreds of years old.
>   If such histories are true, his age is the only part of the High Mage
>   that reflects his elven heritage.

He don't even has the Long Life blood ability to incite any error.

As a counter-point argument, in Blood Enemies book (page 22), Danita Kusor, a half-elf of vos heritage is cited in documents of Daznig (a sage) as a wizard searching for immortality (as she told in a interview) before changing in the awnshegh know as Chimaera. (She could be lying or the sage could be lying to not really risk his life in a interview with a awnshegh - but is a strange situation, since she can be recognized as a half-elf when not in monster form)

So, are half-elves immortal in Cerilia?

Comment: Wikipedia Birthright article claims they are not immortal, but no reference is given.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthright_(campaign_setting)

Comment: @ZwiQ And claims they live longer than humans, but as no reference is given, we can presume they use PhB as basis. In my campaign I was using PhB elf age tables to half-elves as seems more logical to me.

Answer (score 1):

On page 3 of the *Birthright Campaign Setting* rule book, it states:

> In addition to the materials in this box, you need the 2E *Player’s
>   Handbook*, *Dungeon Master’s Guide*, and the *Monstrous Manual* tome to play
>   the Birthright campaign.

There is no aging table in the *Birthright Campaign Setting* rule book, so I would use the Age and Aging effects tables 11 and 12 on page 33 of the 2E *Player’s Handbook*, which says Half-Elves have a life span of [125 + 3d20] years.

Comment: It is a valid answer but I will not click in accept for now because the same can be said about elves, there is no table (if it exists, could have only mental modifiers and minimal playable age), but it stated clearly they are immortal.